# Block element inside custom element inside <p>

Tags: html, web-component, custom-element

I'm using HTML5 Custom Elements to create what might be termed "rich footnotes" (essentially little mouseover boxes).  Markup looks something like

```
<p>
  Socrates is a
  <x-info>
    <x-text>
      man
    </x-text>
    <x-planation>
      <p>What is a man? Here are some examples of men:</p>
      <ul>
        <li>Bill Clinton</li>
        <li>Aristotle</li>
      </ul>
    </x-planation>
  </x-info>, therefore Socrates is mortal
</p>
```

which should render something like

> Socrates is a **man**, therefore Socrates is mortal

such that the box appears when you hover over the word **man**.  This works fine when `<x-info>` contains only inline elements.  However, in the above example the HTML parser gets angry that I have `<p>`s and `<ul>`s nested inside another `<p>`, and mangles the markup so that it renders more like

> Socrates is a man
>
> What is a man? Here are some examples of men:
>
> - Bill Clinton
> - Aristotle
>
> , therefore Socrates is mortal

Is there any way to get around this?  I would like to avoid changing the markup structure, which is somewhat out of my control (otherwise, I will have to preprocess it on the backend).

Comment: You can't do that ever in this lifetime

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1180 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content

Answer (score 1):

The html parser is not 'getting angry', it is the browser that's simply applying default styles to the elements you have used.

A list (ul, ol, dl) is a block-level element, with accepted default styles, and all browsers apply those styles (padding, margin, bullets, numbers, etc.) to these elements in order to *make them look like lists*.

In your case, an unordered list, bulleted list items is the standard rendering for all browsers. Your issue is that you don't want your list to look like a list, so you have two options:

1. Don't use the markup for a list.
2. Remove the default styling for a list.

If you cannot alter the markup, then you'll want option 2, which you can achieve with a little bit of css.

```
ul {display: inline-block; padding: 0, margin: 0; list-style: none}
ul > li {display: inline;}
```

Of course, option one is far easier as you can just use:

```
<p>What is a man? Here are some examples of men: Bill Clinton, Aristotle, therefore Socrates is mortal</p>
```

There's nothing wrong with that semantically, as there's no obvious reason why all the content couldn't be considered a paragraph; especially as that is how you want it to appear.

p.s. In this specific example it would probably be preferable to use the `<dfn>` element to markup the word you are creating a definition for. A definition list `<dl>` would also be a good choice here.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. If you look at https://jsfiddle.net/22p7rams/ and inspect the DOM of the rendered page in your browser, you'll see that the browser is moving the list and nested paragraphs outside root paragraph tag (and outside the custom tags as well). This isn't just a matter of styling.

Then again, in that fiddle I haven't defined the custom elements. Maybe if I did the behavior would be different? Idk...

Comment: The browser is simply trying to make sense of your, incorrect, markup. `<p>` elements cannot contain other block-level elements like `<p>` or `<ul>`, they can only contain inline elements.

Comment: Exactly. My point was that the problem seems to have nothing to do with styling, as this answer suggests.

Comment: It has everything to do with styling. What you are seeing is the result of, sensible, default browser styling. You can change that, of course, with css as detailed in my answer; which is what I understand you want to do. However, as also explained in my answer, it probably makes more sense to use html correctly. I think you'll find you have less issues if you use the correct elements to give the basic styles you want.

Comment: FYI, I'm not the OP. (Your responses to my comments seemed to imply you thought I was.) From what I can see though, the question isn't about styling. The OP is trying to use *custom elements* (looks like the [x-tags](http://www.x-tags.org/) library) to provide a "rich-footnotes" type functionality. The problem is that the browser is moving the footnote content that is supposed to be inside the x-info tag to somewhere else in the document, causing his code to behave incorrectly.